# Pusher creating too many concurrent connections

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket, pusher

I am trying to create a realtime chat application using the pusher library. I am using Next.js. I followed the documentation and the realtime functionality works, but when I am just messing around with the website I create many concurrent connections.

I found this article by pusher: [Why Am I Seeing More Channels Connections Than I Expect?](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412005664273-Why-Am-I-Seeing-More-Channels-Connections-Than-I-Expect-).

It says:
In you are using React, you will need to initialize it in your useEffect with an empty dependency array []. This useEffect will only run once on page initialization.

```
React.useEffect(() => { 
    const pusher = new Pusher("APP_KEY", {cluster: "CLUSTER"});
}, [])
```

I did this in my project yet it continues to keep making too many connections.

This is what I have tried:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_KEY!, {
      cluster: "us3",
    });
    const channel = pusher.subscribe("channel");

    const eventHandler = () => {
      console.log("event");
    };
    channel.bind("event", eventHandler);

    return () => {
      channel.unbind("event", eventHandler);
      pusher.unsubscribe("channel");
      pusher.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

I tried doing this in my _app.tsx, in just a random file, I tried it without the pusher.disconnect() at the end, I tried importing the pusher instance from another file like I saw in a video. No matter what I try whenever I navigate between pages it always creates more pusher connections.

Pusher docs say it should automatically only create one connection and reuse that but thats not what is happening me.

If there is any more information that would be helpful to solve this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? I am seeing the same issue with my NextJs app after upgrading to v14/app dir.

Comment: No I never solved it. I just gave up on pusher. I felt like a lot of their documentation was contradictory and outdated. I am going to check out supabase realtime and see how that goes.

Comment: Yeah. Ran into this issue after 1+ year of prod use with Pusher. Haven't heard from their support in a week and there's no way to terminate open connections that are anonymous. Moving to self-hosted Soketi.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same behaviour, but only in development.

When deploying to production on Vercel there is only one pusher instance being created throughout the whole app.

I suspect that `hot module replacement (HMR)` in the dev environment might be the cause, leading to new instances being created without properly clearing the previous ones.

In order to avoid reaching the maximum allowed concurrent connections in dev, you can simply restart the browser and dev environment to clear all pusher instances.

However, when visiting your website in a new tab in production, you will initialize a new pusher instance. If you want to have a single connection shared across multiple tabs, you will have to use `Shared Web Workers`  (https://pusher.com/blog/reduce-websocket-connections-with-shared-workers/#introduction)